# $k[[x]]$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $k$ a field with $\bar{k}=k$. What can be said about the ideals of $k[[x]]$, can they be determined? I am looking for a $k[[x]]$-module $S$ such that the map $s\mapsto xs$ is surjective, does such a module exist? This is why I am interested in the ideals, as they would give plenty of such examples. Also is there an f.g. $k[[x]]$-module such that $s\mapsto xs$ is surjective? In this case it would have to be an isomorphism (true for any f.g. module), so I somehow suspect the answer is no.

Comment: Let's all take a nitpick vaccine and read between the lines that the OP is looking for a nonzero module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a field $k$, $k[[x]]$ (the ring of [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_ring#The_ring_of_formal_power_series)) is always a domain whose ideals are linearly ordered, and in fact the nontrivial ones are exactly $(x^i)$ for positive integers $i$.

So you are out of luck using ideals: multiplication by $x$ is never surjective on these, it always maps $(x^i)$ down to $(x^{i+1})$, a proper subset.

If you go up a level to the Laurent series $k((x))$, it's obvious that when $k((x))$ acts on itself, multiplication by $x$ is surjective since $x$ is a unit there. If you just restrict this action to $k[[x]]$ acting on $k((x))$, it will still remain so.

> *What about a f.g. module?*

Notice that the Jacobson radical of $k[[x]]$ is just $J=(x)$. If multiplication by $x$ were surjective on $M$, then $JM=M$. But if $M$ is f.g., then Nakayama's lemma says $M=\{0\}$. So, there are no nonzero f.g. modules on which multiplication by $x$ is surjective.

Comment: and what about an f.g. module?

Comment: @KarlKäfer I added a line about it.